# SAS FIRST.VARIABLE giving no output

Tags: sas

I have some SAS code along the lines of:

```
DATA MY_SAMPLE;
    SET SAMPLE;
    BY A;
    IF A = 1 THEN B = 1;
    ELSE IF A ^= 1 THEN B = 0;
    ELSE IF MISSING(A) THEN B = .;
    IF FIRST.A;
RUN;
```

which is returning a set with 0 observations (it shouldn't do this).  I have sorted the data by A and tried reading the data into an intermediate dataset before applying the IF FIRST.A but get the same results.

Am I missing something completely obvious?  I use the FIRST and LAST all of the time!

Comment: A code looks fine, only `ELSE IF` statements are in improper order. Are you sure you have observations in `SAMPLE` dataset?

Comment: This is not a good question.  If the data step is returning `0` observations, then the source dataset is empty.  You should be paying more attention to what your log is telling you.

Answer (score 2):

Agree with @Robert, the sample code should output records, assuming there are records in your input data and it is sorted.

I would double-check the log from your real program/data, and make sure there are no errors, and that the input dataset has records.

If that doesn't help, I would add some debugging PUT statements, something like below (untested):

```
DATA MY_SAMPLE;
    SET SAMPLE;
    BY A;

    IF A = 1 THEN B = 1;
    ELSE IF A ^= 1 THEN B = 0;
    ELSE IF MISSING(A) THEN B = .;  *This will never be true ;

    put "Before subsetting if " (_n_ A first.A)(=) ;
    IF FIRST.A;
    put "After subsetting if  " (_n_ A first.A)(=) ;
RUN;
```

As Robert noted, as written your `Else if Missing(A)` would never be true, because if A is missing the prior `Else if A ^= 1` will evaluate to true because SAS uses binary logic (true/false), not trinary logic(true/false/null).

Also I would check for any stray `OUTPUT` statements in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Checked the log; checked the input; closed MSSQL down; opened it up again and lo and behold, code worked first time.  Thanks for the downgrade, but I didn't realize that MSSQL is prone to twitches!